# Change the owership of files inside a Minetest snap from root to me

Tags: command-line, permissions, games, root, snap

I tried using terminal but all I get is file or directory does not exist. The location on my computer is `/snap/minetest-luk3yx/6/share/minetest/games/minetest_game/mods`.

- I want to put mods on my game in this folder.
- I want to change ownership of the whole Minetest not just specific
  files in it.
- I want them all to be under my ownership, so I can edit as I see fit.
  but it is under root ownership.

Please give step-by-step instructions.

I use Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: If this is a game that is part of Ubuntu Snap, you should say so (and also use the Snap tag.)

Answer (score 1):

The path you have specified is read-only, even to superuser, as shown at https://snapcraft.io/docs/reference/confinement. You should use a different path.

The correct location to store your data for this application is `~/snap/minetest-luk3yx/6`. If there aren't folders named `mods` and `games` inside  `6`, you can create them.

Answer (score 0):

try the command :

```
sudo chown <your username>:<your usergroup> -R <the path to the file><file name>
```

this should make you the owner

### OR

if you just want to edit the file you can use

```
sudo chmod 775 <file path><file name>
```

this makes you read and write and execute the file
so you can edit it easily .

Comment: as per OP, minetest has been installed using snap -- this means that it is inside a read only mounted SquashFS filesystem. the config file can be copied in /etc and then edited and the location of the new config file can be specified on the command line minetest --config